# Android Login- checking if username and password match with MySQL database

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am working on an android app and kinda new in app development. PHP and MySQL are being used for backend. I am building the login page and I want to check if username and password match with database after JSON parsing. I have already parsed JSON and now only the check part is left. I feel like I should make a list and query it using a foreach loop, but I don't know how. Any suggestions or code example would be greatly appreciated! Here is my login and onPostExecute method-

```
public void login(View view) {

    Log.i("username", userNameField.getText().toString());
    Log.i("password", passwordField.getText().toString());

    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
    task.execute("http://something.com.php");


}

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Log.i("Website Content", result);

        try {


           JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result);

          for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

              JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);

         Log.i("user", jsonPart.getString("email"));
         Log.i("pass", jsonPart.getString("password"));

              dbUserName= jsonPart.getString("email");
              dbPassword= jsonPart.getString("password");

         // if ((userName == dbUserName) && (password == (dbPassword))){

           //  Log.i("AppInfo", "Login Successful!");

        //   }
         // else{
         //   Log.i("Appinfo", "you suck");
         //   }

          } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If your query was along the lines of `select * from users where name = ? and password = ?"  then there will either be a result (GOOD) or not

Comment: When you register the user for the first time and post it details to the server, get a userId , which you can save in your db with the username and password. Let it be unique. and the next time during login ,query with the UserId. And check if username and password match with database.

Comment: I think it should be compare at the server ,then the server returns something pass or failed...

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to write for each loop.You have to make a GET/POST call to something.com.php and **send your username and password to the server**.

Then you have to check weather the username and password matches with your database.Write that logic in **something.com.php**

If it is a match send a **success flag to your app as 1 and 0 otherwise.**

**Parse the success flag** in your app and check weather it is 0 or 1.

Based on it let the user login your app.

See:

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-php-mysql-login-tutorial-android-login-app-3/

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Answer (score 1):

You need to send Login details to server and check on server for success or fail then do as per response in your app Here is brief example of it

1. First get user name and password from edit text

> ```
> String UserName=EditText_UserName.getText().toString();
> String Password=EditText_Password.getText().toString();
> ```

2. Send these Strings to AsyncTask like this

> `new asynctask().execute(UserName,Password)`

3. Get Username and Password in doInBackground(String...params)

> `Phone=params[0];`
>
> `Password=params[1];`

3:Encode Username and password in single string like this

```
> String data = URLEncoder.encode("UserName", "UTF-8") + "=" +
> URLEncoder.encode(UserName, "UTF-8");
> data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("Password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Password, "UTF-8");
```

4:Now Write data to URL with help of `BufferedWriter`

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.Example.com/Login.php");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(data);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();
```

5: Now in Php file compare result with data base and send response back to android app like this

```
//Get Values first 
$UserName=$_POST['UserName'];
$Password =$_POST['Password'];

//then compare it in SQL DATABASE
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mobile_App WHERE  UserName = '$UserName' AND Password = '$Password'";

//Send Response to app if query success
$response['status'] = 'SUCCESS'; 

//else send failed
```

6:Check Response Code in App

```
int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();//It will return 200 if Connection Established with server
//Get Success String or Fail String By InputStream
```

7: Finally compare string from server Success or Fail and then do further.